# How to handle camera flash android camera2 API?

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to set flash off,on and auto as user selection. How should I do that?

In this code if I enable flash it is on but when I click image flash goes off. And when I change camera at that time also flash goes off.

If the user sets flash to `enable` then when the user clicks an image only at that time flash should go on and after that it should be off.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;


    private boolean deviceHasFlash;
    private boolean flashStatus=false;
    private String cameraId=CAMERA_BACK;
    private Size imageDimension;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private static final int PERMISSION_CODE = 200;
    public static final String CAMERA_FRONT = "1";
    public static final String CAMERA_BACK = "0";
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    ImageView captureImage;
    ImageView flash;
    ImageView switchCamera;
    private TextureView textureView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        captureImage = findViewById(R.id.btn_camera_shutter);
        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        flash=findViewById(R.id.btn_flash);
        switchCamera=findViewById(R.id.btn_camera_switch);
        if (checkPermission()) {

            setCameraView();
            createFolderIfNotExists();

            Log.e("DB", "Permission is Given");

        } else {
            Log.e("DB", "Ask For Permission");
            requestPermission();
        }
        captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
        switchCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switchCameraFunction();
            }
        });
        flash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deviceHasFlash = getApplication().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
                if(!deviceHasFlash){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry, you device does not have any camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    if(flashStatus){
                        flashOff();
                        flash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_off);
                        flashStatus=false;
                    }
                    else {
                        flashOn();
                        flash.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_flash_on);
                        flashStatus=true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void switchCameraFunction() {
        if (cameraId.equals(CAMERA_FRONT)) {
            cameraId = CAMERA_BACK;
            closeCamera();
            reopenCamera();

        } else if (cameraId.equals(CAMERA_BACK)) {
            cameraId = CAMERA_FRONT;
            closeCamera();
            reopenCamera();

        }
    }

    private void reopenCamera() {
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            Log.e("DB", "reopenCamera if");
            openCamera();
        } else {
            Log.e("DB", "reopenCamera else");
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);

        }
    }

    private void flashOff() {
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void flashOn() {
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setCameraView() {

        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
    }

    private void createFolderIfNotExists() {
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "CrazyCam");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
            if (success) {
                Log.e("DB", "Folder Created");
            } else {
                Log.e("DB", "Something Wrong");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("DB", "Folder exists");
        }

    }

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int readExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int writeExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);

        return camera == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && writeExternal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && readExternal == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean wrireExteernal = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean readExternal = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (wrireExteernal && cameraAccepted && readExternal) {
                        setCameraView();
                        createFolderIfNotExists();
                        Log.e("DB", "Permission is Given");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All Permission Requeid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        System.exit(0);

                    }


                }
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e("DB", "is camera open");
        try {

            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            Log.e("DB","imageDimension===>"+imageDimension);
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_CODE);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("DB", "openCamera X");
    }

    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

            openCamera();
            Log.e("DB","onSurfaceTextureAvailable");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e("DB", "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }

    };

   /* @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        closeCamera();
        Log.e("DB","On Destroy Call");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
*/
    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e("DB", "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            Log.e("DB", "textureView if");
            openCamera();
        } else {
            Log.e("DB", "textureView else");
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);

        }


    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.e("DB", "onPause");
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();

        super.onPause();
    }
    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(imageDimension.getWidth(), imageDimension.getHeight());
            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e("DB", "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    protected void takePicture() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e("DB", "cameraDevice is null");
            return;
        }
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            for(int i=0;i<jpegSizes.length;i++){
                Log.e("DB==>","Size:"+jpegSizes[i]);
            }
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
            }
            ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
            List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
            outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
            outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            // Orientation
            int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            final File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                    File.separator + "CrazyCam");
            String fileName = String.format("CrazyCam_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            final File outFile = new File(folder, fileName);
            ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image image = null;
                    try {
                        image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                        buffer.get(bytes);
                        save(bytes);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        if (image != null) {
                            image.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;

                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                        outStream.write(bytes);
                        outStream.flush();

                    } finally {
                        if (null != outStream) {
                            outStream.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
            final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Save at " + folder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    createCameraPreview();
                }
            };
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    try {
                        session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think that you'll get all of your code read. you'll get answered by a code snippet that shows you how to do it.

Comment: please see this repo on GitHub, https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Camera